# How to call method on ticking the SelectAll checkbox in p:dataTable through ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I need your help in calling a method from a backing bean once I ticked the **SelectAll** checkbox at the top of a dataTable. I am able to call the method **ShowTotal**
once I ticked or unticked the checkbox of each individual item, however when I tick the **SelectAll** checkbox from the top, no listener is called. Here is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="PendingRequests" var="hr" selection="#{hrdirector.selectedRequests}"
             value="#{hrdirector.listPendingRequests}" rowKey="#{hr.requestNo}"
             filteredValue="#{hrdirector.filteredRequests}" widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar">
  <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{hrdirector.ShowTotal}" process="@this" 
          update=":form:PendingRequests:sum"/>

  <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{hrdirector.ShowTotal}" process="@this"
          update=":form:PendingRequests:sum"/>

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"></p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Request No.">
            <h:outputText value="#{hr.requestNo}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Request Amount">
            <h:outputText value="#{hr.requestAmount}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <h:outputText id="Sum" value="#{hr.Sum}"/>
```

I tried to add the below code in the column which it has the selection, but it gave me an error:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center">
<p:ajax listener="#{hrdirector.ShowTotal}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: Next time, please try to read the fabulous/fine manual. It is there for a reason

Comment: And as in another post of you, methods in java start by convention with a lowercase

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your advice. Actually I am only checking the showcase only as it is easy to understand and there are examples but I am missing alot by not to check the documentation.

Comment: Yes, not everything is in the showcase, not by a long shot

Comment: And if the answer was realy helpful (in suggestig to use the docs more ;-) ) and upvote is in place…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 172 of the fabulous PrimeFaces documentation has the answer for you. What you need is called the toggleSelect event.

Comment: I think you should just remove the page reference here as the manual can be updated and the answer can change in page location.